# java.lang.StackOverflowError while using LWJGL's Keyboard class

Tags: java, keyboard, lwjgl

I have been trying to implement a Keyboard class into my game and received the exception below. This is just a snippet. The full exception goes on for ages longer than this.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode.<init>(DisplayMode.java:63)
at oregon.client.Oregon.<init>(Oregon.java:10)
at oregon.src.Controller.<init>(Controller.java:9)
at oregon.client.Oregon.<init>(Oregon.java:12)
at oregon.src.Controller.<init>(Controller.java:9)
at oregon.client.Oregon.<init>(Oregon.java:12)
at oregon.src.Controller.<init>(Controller.java:9)
```

Here's the code for the main class (oregon.client.Oregon):

```
package oregon.client;

import oregon.src.Controller;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;

public class Oregon {
    public DisplayMode normal = new DisplayMode(640, 640);

    public Controller controls = new Controller();

    public boolean fullscreen = false;

    public void start() {
        try {
            create();
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            stop(e);
        }

        while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
            events();
            Display.update();
        }

        Display.destroy();
    }

    public void events() {
        try {
            controls.getInput();
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            stop(e);
        }
    }

    public void setFullscreen() {
        try {
            if (!fullscreen) {
                Display.setFullscreen(true);
                fullscreen = true;
            } else if (fullscreen) {
                Display.setDisplayMode(normal);
                fullscreen = false;
            }
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            stop(e);
        }
    }

    public void create() throws LWJGLException {
        if (fullscreen) {
            Display.setFullscreen(true);
        } else if (!fullscreen) {
            Display.setDisplayMode(normal);
        }

        Display.create();
    }

    public void stop() {
        System.exit(0);
        Display.destroy();
    }

    public void stop(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
        Display.destroy();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Oregon oregon = new Oregon();
        oregon.start();
    }
}
```

And here's the code for my keyboard class:-

```
package oregon.src;

import oregon.client.Oregon;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;

public class Controller {
    public Oregon oregon = new Oregon();

    public void getInput() throws LWJGLException {
        while (Keyboard.next()) {
            if (Keyboard.getEventKeyState()) {
                if (Keyboard.getEventKey() == Keyboard.KEY_F11) {
                    oregon.setFullscreen();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If there is an expert out the with LWJGL, could you please help me out? Thank you and I hope I do get some help. :D

Answer (score 3):

Nothing to do with LWJGL. Stack overflows in simple code are always because of accidental infinite loops. You have one: `Controller` tries to create an `Oregon` (this line: `public Oregon oregon = new Oregon();)`, which then tries to create a `Controller`, which tries to... (etc..)

Comment: I changed the "public Oregon oregon = new Oregon();" from the Controller class to "public Oregon oregon;" but now I have a NullPointerException. Could you help?

Answer (score 2):

When you create an `Oregon` instance, it creates a `Controller` instance, which creates an `Oregon` instance, which creates a `Controller` instance, which creates an...

What you should probably be doing is not creating an `Oregon` instance in your controller, but passing your existing instance as a parameter to the `Controller` constructor and storing that (or the other way around).

Pseudo code:

```
public Oregon() {
  controller = new Controller(this);
  ...
}
```

```
public Controller(Oregon oregon) {
  this.oregon = oregon;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't refreshed! :)